# Getting `null value in column "id" of relation table_name` when I try to save something to the database in Phoenix

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Every time I try to run a `Repo.insert` with this particular table, I get an error about the id being null (`null value in column "id" of relation table_name`), but the id isn't supposed to be set manually anyway, so why would I need to set it explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was that I was using binary ids for this schema, and I had forgotten to add these lines

```
@primary_key {:id, :binary_id, autogenerate: true}
@foreign_key_type :binary_id
```

to the schema file to reflect that. Because of that, the `id` field was not getting automatically set the way it should.

Comment: cool, maybe next time it would be nice if you also add schema and migration in the question, it gives more context.